Interested in the SE moderation process?
Then the assembly is the room you need.
As some of you may or may not know, moderators have a room that's hidden from public eyes. There's several reasons for this:

We need, sometimes, to discuss private user details.
We sometimes get heads up on decisions that might be pulled

etc. You get the idea. However, a lot of stuff can and should be discussed in public.
This is where the assembly comes in. This is a new room where moderators from many different sites on the network can come together to discuss things we can discuss in the open - migrations, how to handle certain types of questions etc.
Anyone with any constructive comments, or who simply wishes to ask a few questions, is welcome to join us. I will not always be there, but mods from other sites will.
What to expect:

Moderators will always be there - you can tell who we are, our names are in blue.
It will be fairly busy at times.
You will get a much wider variety of views. Not everyone will agree on every policy or way of doing things.
"Trolling" ("modz suck") is unlikely to be tolerated. This has consequences for your network-wide chat account, so keep it constructive. I probably don't need to say this given we've had next to no problems on crypto, really, but hey.

So yes, feel free to come along if you are at all interested in what happens.
